# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError-- Stuck

Tags: java

I am stuck with this exception and I can't seem to get around. How to rid this off? Here it is.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: myBlog/DAOImpls/DAOImplMan

```
at myBlog.Handlers.HandlerMan.saveComment(HandlerMan.java:34)
at myBlog.Services.ServiceMan.saveComments(ServiceMan.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
```

In the HandlerMan class i have this method which calls for an instance of DAOImplMan class

```
public Comment saveComment(Comment comment){
     DAOImplMan.getInstance().saveComment(comment);
     return comment;
}
```

and the DAOImplMan class is like this.

```
package myBlog.DAOImpls;
public class DAOImplMan extends BaseDAOHibernateImpl implements DAOMan{
    private static DAOImplMan INSTANCE = null;

    public static DAOImplMan getInstance(){
        if(INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = new DAOImplMan();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveComment(Comment comment){//some codes}
```

I have looked at other posts that deals with this kind of exception. My classpaths are set right. and I actually don't have this kind of exception in my other projects. And I can't dig any further on my own.

Comment: Actually, this exception tells you that your classpaths are NOT set right.

Comment: please show the package declaration. It is looking for package "myBlog.DAOImpls"

Comment: This should have been a compile-time error, too. Are you sure all the code in your project has been re-compiled properly?

Comment: @Thilo, thanks for responding. WEll i have the package declaration which i ignored but i have included them at the start.

Comment: @Andrew , well i am looking into it again.

Comment: @Thilo there is no compile time error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all of your project .class files and redeploy again. Check this is location of class file in your project.

[image]

Comment: there is no .class file in my project. something's going wrong?

Comment: Ye Yan   i appreciate your response. Let me see again.

Comment: @tamthingshimray There was no class and "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" found. Rebuild until class files have occur or test with other IDE like eclipse

Comment: it's giving me now different exceptions. But i am trying to do something. can i delete the build folder?

Comment: hey, it's working now. i deleted the classes like you said and tried deploying but it won't work saying classes not found. then i deleted teh whole build and closed the netbeans and restarted. Then, i performed this: clean+build+deploy+run (for whoever might come across). it worked. :)  I can't thank you enough. I have spent lots of hours just for this. Thank you once again for your effort.

Comment: Yes you can. But don't forget to rebuild again after deleting build folder.

Comment: one thing i figured the cause is that, i created (then deleted), renamed many packages and classes.  So, in the process, in the build folder, i could see all of my old package and class names. deleting them helped in my case.

Answer (score 1):

It you are working with Eclipse, for example, it could be that you classpaht in Eclipse is right so you can compile without any problem. `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` means that class was there in compilation time, but no in runtime, so review your runtime classpath.

Comment: i am working on netbeans. How do i review my runtime classpath and what should i observe there?

Comment: Where are you running your application? Web application?

Comment: Glassfish on netbeans. windows 7. you asking that?

Comment: Because if it is running on a Web application server, probably the problem is there. Even though your class/library is there for Netbeans (no compilation problem) probably is not there for Glassfish so focus on to the deployment configuration and find out why your class/library is not present on it.